# How to create a checkbox by a function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am new to javascript and html coding.I am trying to make a button and "onclick" button will call a function. And the function would  create a checkbox.
Is it like its impossible to create such a function as script part of the code would be unable to read html tags????

Comment: *"Is it like its impossible to create such a function as script part of the code would be unable to read html tags"* I'm not sure what you mean by that, but it's really easy to create DOM elements in the browser. I recommend to read http://quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html. You might also want to learn more about event handling: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Comment: thnx a lot FELIX KLING..!!!! I appreciate ur help!!

Answer (score -2):

jQuery my friend

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    $('#someDiv').append('<input type="checkbox"/>');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yVe3N/)

Comment: Not sure who/why DV was added...

Comment: @Phlume: The JavaScript tag description says: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."* Besides, just posting a code snippet without an explanation or an explanation of what jQuery is, is not very useful IMO.

Comment: Since the user claimed to be new to HTML js, it's safe to assume they wouldn't know to include a tag to jquery.  Further, since the user claimed to be new, jQuery would be an important thing to be aware of.  Ask 20 developers how to do this and 99% of them will give the same answer so why give the user an answer that most wouldn't provide.